# IP wildcards in script

Tags: powershell, dns

I wrote a script to query DNS for IP address and host-names, this works great but I'd like to further prune my data and only show results of IP address 10.9.x.x, does anyone know a good way to do this?

```
get-wmiobject -ComputerName DNSServer -Namespace root\microsoftDNS -Class MicrosoftDNS_ResourceRecord -Filter "domainname='contoso.local'"| select ipaddress, ownername |sort ownername
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the result using the [`Where-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx) cmdlet (alias `?`):

```
... | select ipaddress, ownername | ? { $_.ipaddress -like '10.9.*' } |
  sort ownername
```

Comment: That worked thank you. I did try the where-object cmdlet I guess I didn't have the correct syntax